# Using ONLY Pamusb as authentication

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, pam

Is it possible to **only** use pamusb to login (into xfce/lightdm) and not have a password at all?

When I try to change pamusb to required in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and comment out the password thingie I get "Authentication Failed" on the login screen, even before I do anything at all.
Help appreciated!

Comment: Before executing the command, make sure you type in the Terminal (use TTY 1-6 or Ctrl+Alt+T) `sudo -i` and type your password in, this makes you root until you close/stop using the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it after all.
You don't have to edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file, but the file in `/usr/share/pam-configs/usb`to have it said as exclusive.

[The Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/pamusb) has some  very good information on the topic.